# Playing audio from web.api in browser

Tags: html, asp.net-web-api, audio

We have a database of audio files which we need to play in a browser.  What is the correct approach for setting up the  html component to load an audio file from a web api backend?  Something like this (which doesn't work, by the way):

```
<audio controls><source src="/api/audio/1" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

This is my controller code:

```
var path = @"path to file - the data could just as easily come from our database";
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the file extension of your audio file? is it 1.mp3  maybe specify it in your  src path?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd do that since the source is just a path to the api method